# DHCP from Cisco 1921 failing after switch nr 2

Tags: cisco, dhcp

I have a network which uses a Cisco 1921 router. The router is connected to a Dell Powerconnect 2848 switch and from that switch is a connection to a small SOHO Planet switch which 3 computers connect to. These 3 computers do not get an IP allocated from the Cisco router (or the win 2008r2 server which is partly responsible for the DHCP pool, nr 200 to 224, the win2008r2 is connected to the Dell Powerconnect).

I have heard that Cisco can refuse DHCP from clients that are on a second switch, how do I check if my router is doing that?

These 3 computers net works fine if I put them on a static IP address.

TIA

Comment: Are you sure that DHCP on Cisco router is running? Could you check it with 'sh run ip dhcp'?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of that, I can see several computers that are only connected through the first switch that are getting IP bindings.

Comment: `I have heard that Cisco can refuse DHCP from clients that are on a second switch` - Where did you hear that? That sounds like nonsense. How would the router know how many switches there are? Have you checked the DHCP pool on the router and the server to make sure they aren't full? Do the ip pools on the router and the server overlap? Have you run a packet capture to see what's happening?

Comment: The DHCP pools aren't full, only about 40 or 50 out of about 180 are being used. The pools do not overlap, one stops at 199, the other starts at 200. Running wireshark on a failed connection shows some Discover, Request packets, one Ack packet from the router and thats about it. There are two Offer packets from the server but no Inform or Ack following that.

As for the switch rumor I heard, isn't it so that each time a packet goes through a switch an extra layer is added on it, and can't the router then count the layers from that? Just wondering.

Comment: "Offer packets from the server" - you mean from the router? So router works, clients do not accept offers? Please try to find chains of Discover - Offer - Request - Ack, as mentioned on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Operation)

Comment: Oh, a lot of clients get IP addresses from the router so he works very well except for the clients that are behind the second switch, they don't get an IP address from the router. Running wireshark on one of those clients showed an IP offer from the windows server, but no offers from the router.

Comment: Why would you run two DHCP pools for a single subnet? And how is the link between SW1 and SW2 configured?